# AWS Lambda function is unable to access node_modules in layer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created a lambda function that relies on some dependencies in a node_modules folder.

I had originally created the lambda with a node_modules folder inside of it, and it worked fine when testing.

I then created a layer, uploaded the node_modules folder to it, and set the runtime to Node.js 8.10.

I then added the layer to the lambda, created a policy with the following JSON, and added the policy to the role associated with the lambda:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "lambda:GetLayerVersion",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I test the Lambda, then dependencies that I am trying to include from the node_modules folder located within the associated layer are not found.

Update:

I've also run the following command:

> aws lambda add-layer-version-permission --layer-name node_modules --version-number 2 \
>   --statement-id publish --action lambda:GetLayerVersion --principal "*"

But the problem has not been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the NODE_PATH environment variable for your lambda to be

```
NODE_PATH: './:/opt/node_modules'
```

This way you don't need to have `opt/node_modules` in your code when you import something.

Answer (score 0):

The layer worked after I required dependencies with "/opt/node_modules" path like so:

```
const mongoose = require("/opt/node_modules/mongoose");
const mongo = require("/opt/node_modules/mongodb");
```